# Loading local jquery.js file in node js

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, socket.io

I want to load local jquery file in my node js chat application.I have searched a lot but i cant find a proper solution.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Socketio</title>
  </head>
  <body>
      <!--This wont work -->
      <script src="/socket.io/jquery.min.js"></script> 
        <!--This will work -->
      <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

I just copy jquery.js file to `socket.io` folder.The `socket.io.js` file loads properly but jquery file didnt.Please help me
Here is my index.js file

```
var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);


app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

server.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

Comment: What do you need jQuery on server side for ? Maybe you want to load it on index.html ?

Comment: Yes i want  to load file in client

Comment: Than just place it as you would normally do on index.html

Comment: But it didnt work .i will get the error cannot GET jquery file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the answer.I simply load the jquery file from localhost by this way `http://localhost/assets/jquery.min.js`.

Answer (score 1):

```
app.use('/assets', express.static('assets'))
```

Put your jquery.min.js file in relative "/assets/jquery.min.js" path, then access as http://localhost/assets/jquery.min.js

"localhost" could be your ip address also.

Personally, I need this because I need a completely self contained demo to run independant of an available internet connection.  Murphy's law is alive and well come conference time.

Answer (score 0):

You might want allow Express framework to render HTML and pass in the static jQuery files. That's how I would do it.

[This page](http://expressjs.com/starter/faq.html) explains how you can restructure your app to serve jquery files through the node routes instead of HTML code.

Comment: Its little bit complicated.

Answer (score 0):

```
app.get('/jquery', function(res, req){
   res.sendFile(__dirname + '/jquery.js');
});
```

Comment: Could you please explain this?

Comment: Sorry for late explanation. This means response will be **jquery.js** if you send request to `baseurl/jquery`.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me. (inside app.js)

```
const express = require('express');//path to express module
const path = require('path');
const app = express();
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

My file structure looked like this:

```
  server.js
  app.js
> public
    index.html
  > assets
    > js
        jquery.min
```

Then import jquery from index.html like normal:

```
<script src="assets/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

One workaround is to use the online source file link.
Try loading the jquery using the following,

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

That works fine at my end.